# How to implement turn-based logic into Socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to make a turn-based game using Node.js and Socket.IO

Currently, when a player uses a move, the server thinks that it's the next players turn. Here's a visual:

```
player that's supposed to go
           v   player that's not supposed to go.        
                      v
["Bob","Janet",    "Mark", "Jane"]
```

Server Events:

```
socket.on('start_game', function(data) {
    let groupIndex = games.findIndex(function(item) {
        return item.name === data.group.name;
    });
    if (groupIndex > -1) {
        let playerIndex =  games[groupIndex].players.findIndex(function(item) {
            return item.id === data.player.id;
        });
        if (playerIndex > -1) {
            if (games[groupIndex].players[playerIndex].leader) {
                games[groupIndex].started = true;
                console.log("============== Started Game ==============");
                gameNSP.to(games[groupIndex].name).emit("started_game");
            }
        }
    }
});

socket.on('pass_turn', function(data) {
    let groupIndex = games.findIndex(function(item) {
        return item.name === data.group.name;
    });
    if (groupIndex > -1) {
        if (games[groupIndex].started) {
            console.log(games[groupIndex].players[games[groupIndex]._turn], data.player);
            if (games[groupIndex].players[games[groupIndex]._turn].id == data.player.id) {
                console.log("Passing Turn", data);
                games[groupIndex].resetTimeOut();
                games[groupIndex].next_turn(data.move);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Game.js: https://gist.github.com/Hydrosaur/54b8bbe25aeccaa376adefc5fd375089

Comment: Could you give some more information? What does row 24 of Game.js print for example? Which is the place where you expected some result but got a wrong one?

Comment: @ntakwing this._turn starts at zero when the first person makes their turn but then the client sees the person one index after as their name.

Comment: I suppose on line 24 you get the right results. My next suspect would be line 25 in Game.js. In some place in your code you are matching the socketIDs to the players. Are you positive that the matching is being done correctly? As a sidenote, I see that you have two ways of identifying a player. The socketID and the player.id. Perhaps you could get rid of the player.id. :-)